# How to create a blank frame with absolute positions of paragraphs and images (beamer)?

Tags: beamer, geometry

I would like to create a frame that is absolutely filled with contents of either images or paragraphs. Images should stretch for the entire space of their boxes. For paragraphs, I think it would be good to add 3mm margins from left and right edges of their boxes. The original background should be replaced with white one as shown here (similar to when we create a template for a note page) and any other contents (such as miniframe hyperlinks or palettes) should be removed even if no contents will be written above them.

The lines below are for illustration but it would also be good for them to (optionally) exist to allow easier reading or debugging later on. Being able to create 2 by 3 grid of boxes is also great to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
        \AtPageCenter{\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}%
                        }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just use \documentclass{slides} or pdfscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this, however with the price of double compilation, is to use TikZ:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{tikz,calc}

\author{TeX.SE}
\title{How to place absolutely on a plain frame}

\begin{document}
    
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south east] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{example-image-b}};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{example-image-c}};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: This works if the names of the example images are corrected (-a, -b, and -c, not -A, -B, and -C).

Comment: Thanks @Thérèse, next time just edit my post for those small mistakes.